# Portia, how to save data to database?

Tags: python, scrapy, portia

In portia, I want to save the data to the database like Mysql or do something to clean the data, but I don't know how to do that, can you give me some suggestion.
I'm new in scrapy, and I'll wait online, thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to include any code you have tried, as well as descriptions of the database.  It's extremely difficult to help with something so vague.

Comment: sorry,I want to save the data the crawler download,or do something like the parse in scrapy's spider,I mean I want to how where can I change it in my project,thanks for your reply！

Comment: Thanksfor your attention, I find a solution

Comment: this is a good question, I DON'T  know why some guys downvoted it !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new item processing pipeline for storing data to MySQL. To do this you need to go to the Portia project folder, add a new pipelines.py file that can save data to MySQL and edit the settings.py file to use this pipeline.

Here is an example of an item pipeline for storing data in MySQL

https://github.com/darkrho/dirbot-mysql/blob/master/dirbot/pipelines.py#L36

Here is the documentation on how to enable the pipeline and how it works

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html